# Incomprehensible htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm currently trying to rewrite url with the mod rewrite and htaccess.
Here is my htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^lul$     lol/index.html [L]

    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Url requested : /lul.
And this rewrite the url to /app/webroot/lul. How is that possible?
If I delete the 2 lasts lines (app/webroot/ lines) then the rewrite works correctly (the index.html file just displays "Hello", and the rewrited url is /lol/index.html).

How and why is my code not working ?

Comment: Because your last rule says, redirect anything to aap/webroot/anything and since you do not verify or force stop any of your rules it will get executed in chain. The `L` flag stands for LAST but it does not impose it, unlike the flag `END` available in apache 2.4 and above which means we are done after this rule if it matches.

Comment: The [L] flag is actually normally there to say that if the rule is applied then the rewrite is over EDIT: Ok i'm trying then ;)

Comment: that is a huge misinterpretation of what it actually does, which you can easily see if you use apache's RewriteLog

Comment: Thanks it worked. Well I was using htacess tester online and It wrote me this so I didnt really know. Can you add this as an answer so I can set it resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Prix :

Because your last rule says, redirect anything to aap/webroot/anything and since you do not verify or force stop any of your rules it will get executed in chain. The L flag stands for LAST but it does not impose it, unlike the flag END available in apache 2.4 and above which means we are done after this rule if it matches.

Comment: `L` does what it is supposed to do. `L` acts like a `continue` in **while loop** whereas `END` acts like a `break.